# How can one make GraphQL queries and mutations _from_ Apollo Server?

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

We have a large project which will have a large number of distinct data sources/microservices -- some of these will be REST API, some GraphQL.  We want to make an intermediary layer between those data sources and our final client, which will be NextJS/React/Apollo Client.  Apollo Server seems a good choice for this -- receive data from the different data sources/microservices and make a unified GraphQL API that the Apollo Client front end will consume.  Similarly, when we need to post data from the front end, provide a GraphQL interface which will either post REST API or GraphQL to the data sources.

The one thing I'm having trouble with is understanding how to fetch and post data *from* Apollo Server when the original data source/microservice has a GraphQL API.  I looked through the [Apollo Server documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/data/) for fetching data and don't see what I'm looking for -- perhaps I'm missing it.

How would one do that if Apollo Server doesn't provide the API to actually fetch GraphQL data?  Use Apollo Client in the Apollo Server?

I'm sure I'm missing the blindingly obvious, and would appreciate any clues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a GraphQL gateway server.

Check these links -

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/federation/implementing/

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/schema-delegation/#example

> Edit

Case 1 - If you have microservices that are written in Graphql, so using the apollo gateway server you can stitch all the schema from all other microservices into one single schema which can be consumed by the client. It is easy to set up and manage. Even if in future you want to stitch your Graphql backends into one schema then it would be easy to scale and manage with minimal changes.

Case 2- If those microservices are a third party and you don't want to merge those schemas into one then you can use the Apollo server (without gateway) and write a wrapper resolvers that makes an external call.

You can simply use `fetch API` to make a network call from your resolvers.  The creation of a Rest request is easy but the 
  creation of complex Graphql requests (using fragments) might be difficult in 
   case of fetch.

For rest calls - You can use Apollo [RestDataScource](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/data-sources/) to make external rest calls. It also supports apollo server caching.

For Graphql calls - you can use [GraphqlDataSource](https://github.com/poetic/apollo-datasource-graphql/blob/master/src/GraphQLDataSource.ts) or implement your own like this.

Comment: @ I'm looking through the docs you linked to -- I get the impression that these are thought for cases where we are interfacing between systems we ourselves have created, rather than serving as an interface between external backends -- which may be GraphQL, but could also be REST -- and our GraphQL layer (in this case our front).  Would the answer from @ZachChilders be more appropriate for our use-case?  Apollo gateway and federation look very cool, but I wonder if they would be useful here.

Comment: I just found GraphqlDataSource -- is it maintained?  The last commits seem almost a year old.  it's too bad that Apollo don't have their own GraphQL data source.  Would there be anything wrong with simply loading Apollo Client into the server and using that?  Or is that really only to be used inside a React application?

Comment: I'm not sure about GraphqlDataSource maintenance. Apollo team have provided a support for datasource and to  inject it graphql context. It's up to the community to build lib according to their need. Mostly Afaik Apollo client is mostly used on client side. You can simply use apolo link and fetch to make a graphql call as used in GraphqlDataSource. You don't need the whole apollo client package for that.

Comment: GraphqlDataSource looks good to me. You can also implement your own datasource using that

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're overthinking things a bit. You can just use Apollo Client in your intermediary layer to power the resolvers of your Apollo Server.  Short of that, GraphQL servers should respond to a regular POST with the query as a body - you can even use `fetch` for that.